# Ember-cli : define routes outside of the app/routes/ folder

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ecmascript-6

I am currently writing a big Ember.js application. I know Ember.js is quite monolithic but I wanted to drift a bit from this and create modules that I would plug in my application.

I have no problem with component-only modules or those kind of things. My big issue is to import new routes in my Ember-cli application.

Usually I would have my `App.Router` and I could create `App.xxxRoute` whether I define the route in `app/routes/my-route.js` or in `lib/myModule/routes/my-route.js`.

With the Ember-cli ES6 Module syntax, the routes taken into account are only the ones from the `app/routes` folder and as there is no global scope anymore, I can't attach the routes coming from my module to my main application.
This is a bit of a pain.

I have tried a lot of things, ranging from trying to add my routes to the `Ember.Router.router.recognizer` manually (does not work) to creating the routes files in `app/routes` and `export`ing the ones from my modules for each of one of them (but it creates a lot of useless files).

The easiest solution would be to be able to add a directory to the ember-cli path loader or whatever it's called but I'm open to any suggestion.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the [pod structure](http://www.ember-cli.com/#pod-structure) of Ember CLI pod structure what you're looking for? I believe this will support what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks but I know about pods and that's not what I am lookin for at all, I'm really talking about fully detached modules, living in other repositories and added via bower.

Comment: Im not sure but may be this addon will give you an idea of how its done. https://github.com/diogoko/ember-cli-auto-router/

Comment: I think you want to look into building ember cli addons, they can add routes (and other stuff) to the host app.

Comment: Thanks for the insights I'll look into it. It's really cool having some code to look at :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach that I would take is to build an add-on, as mentioned in the comments.

And maybe, depending on your needs, add some initializers that inject objects and anything you like to all your routes or controllers in your app.

See: [Dependency Injection & Service Lookup](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/)

For an example of an add-on that uses initializers you can check [Ember Simple Auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth)